# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named okhttp3.OkHttpClient.connection-pool-total-count already exists

Tags: java, okhttp, mockwebserver

I have upgrade HttpExecutor to v2 version recently. Now start facing duplicate metric issue while running test cases.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named okhttp3.OkHttpClient.connection-pool-total-count already exists
[ERROR] com.main.testSuccessMetadataStore  Time elapsed: 0.088 s  <<< ERROR!
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: 
Unable to provision, see the following errors:
1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: IllegalArgumentException: A metric named okhttp3.OkHttpClient.connection-pool-total-count already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding additional config to my yml for httpconfiguration. The issue was that I was not passing a config **clientId** for HttpConfiguration due to which, for every test case execution a new metric was getting created for the http clients.